# Clicking on a item in listview with custom view in android

Tags: java, android

So I'm using a custom view in on a List view and I'm tring to get the position of the view being clicked on, but I can't even get the debugger to display anything. I don't know what is wrong with this, any help would be appreciated.

```
ListAdapter BryceAdapter=new CustomAdapter(this,Restaurants,imgs);
ListView BryceListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.BryceListView);
BryceListView.setAdapter(BryceAdapter);
BryceListView.setOnItemClickListener(
          new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onItemClick: ");
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `+ position` like so:

```
ListAdapter BryceAdapter=new CustomAdapter(this,Restaurants,imgs);
ListView BryceListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.BryceListView);
BryceListView.setAdapter(BryceAdapter);
BryceListView.setOnItemClickListener(
   new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onItemClick: " + postion);
            }
   }
);
```